# Move a file from one server to another server via plsql or shell

Tags: shell, unix, plsql, ftp

I have a server with details :

```
server ip: 192.168.141.96 : 21     credentials:  user: tss password: T@l30P@ss     path: /home/ttt/
```

This is the server where a file is getting generated. I want to move this file to another server with credentials

```
Host: sftp://sftpabc.learn.com
User name: abc
Password: jQrE7wvg
Port: 22
import dir: upload/source
```

I am trying to use the following plsql script for this :

```
DECLARE
  l_conn  UTL_TCP.connection;
begin
  l_conn := ftp.login('192.168.141.96', '21', 'tss', 'T@l30P@ss');
  ftp.ascii(p_conn => l_conn);
  FTP.GET(P_CONN      => L_CONN,
          P_FROM_FILE => 'filename_test.csv',
          p_to_dir    => 'DIR_INBOUND',
          p_to_file   => 'test_get.txt');
  ftp.logout(l_conn);
END;
```

But this is not executing and no file is getting transgerred. Is there a shell script/plsql script for this ?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by 'is not executing'.  What is the error?  A quick search shows that you may be using [this](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/ftp-from-plsql) site as reference for your code.  If that is the case, did you make sure to compile the ftp.pks and ftp.pkb in your database?